# How to Pass column name in group by from a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Want to extract max values of a column of each group of data frame.

I have column name in a variable which i want to pass in group by condition but it is failing.

I have below data frame:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Gene   Value
             A      12
             A      10
             B      3
             B      5
             B      6
             C      1
             D      3
             D      4')
```

Column values in Variables below:

```
columnselected <- c("Value")
groupbycol <- c("Gene")
```

My Code is :

```
df %>% group_by(groupbycol) %>% top_n(1, columnselected)
```

This code is giving error.

```
  Gene   Value
   A        12
   B         6
   C         1
   D         4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `group_by_at` and without using an additional package

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by_at(groupbycol) %>% 
   top_n(1, !! as.name(columnselected))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Gene [4]
#  Gene  Value
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        12
#2 B         6
#3 C         1
#4 D         4
```

NOTE: There would be many dupes for this post :=)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert column names to symbol using `sym` and then evaluate them using `!!`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(!!sym(groupbycol)) %>% top_n(1, !!sym(columnselected))

#  Gene  Value
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        12
#2 B         6
#3 C         1
#4 D         4
```